# How to clear global filter in PrimeFaces DataTable

Tags: jsf, primefaces

How can I clear global filter in PrimeFaces DataTable using "Clear" CommandButton? I found [similar question on PrimeFaces forum](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=24230), but looks like not answered - the tip one can find there didn't help me. I tried to solve the problem as follows:

```html
<p:dataTable id="myTab" widgetVar="myTabWidgetVar" var="obj"
    value="#{managedBean.objects}">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <p:outputPanel>
            <h:outputText value="Search all fields:"/>
            <p:inputText id="globalFilter" onkeyup="myTabWidgetVar.filter()"/>
        </p:outputPanel>
    </f:facet>
</p:dataTable>
<p:commandButton value="Clear" onclick="myTabWidgetVar.clearFilters();"
    update="@form"/>
```

It clears column filters only. Value in global filter remains uncleared. Can you help me to solve the problem?

Comment: Since the `globalFilter` will be in the end a `<input type="text">` then just clear it's value with vanilla JavaScript or using jQuery (the one that works better for you).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is how:

```
$("#someFormId\\:myTab\\:globalFilter").val("").keyup();//if you got `prependId="false" , than omit the `someFormId\\:` part from the selector and leave only `myTab\\:globalFilter`
```

This will fill your filter with empty string and trigger a keyup event , resulting in clearing your filter and clearing the filter state of the table

If you just want to clear the filter without resetting the filter applied to your table use

```
$("#someFormId\\:myTab\\:globalFilter").val("");
```

If you want to use this code in a commandButton there is no need to use ajax (`update...`)

Just use `onclick` like this

```
<p:commandButton value="Clear" 
onclick="$('#someFormId\\:myTab\\:globalFilter').val('').keyup(); return false;"/>
```

use `return false;` so the button wont submit your page...

Comment: It stopped working when I put "myTab" with enclosing "someFormId" inside composite component. Can you help me once more?

Comment: @Serg, try `$('input[id$="someFormId\\:myTab\\:globalFilter"]').val('').keyup();` or `$('input[id$="someFormId:myTab:globalFilter"]').val('').keyup();` or worst case scenario , try ``$('input[id$="myGlobalFilterUniqueId"]').val('').keyup();``

Comment: thanks for your help. Unfortunately, it doesn't work in my case. I've returned to clearing inputs with backspace.

Comment: If I use that code I lose the current selected data because I use a filter D:

Answer (score 3):

```
<pdataTable  widgetVar="departments" />
<p:commandButton value="#{lang:text('Add department')}"
                 id="....."
                 actionListener="....."
                 update="@form"
                 oncomplete="PF('departments').clearFilters()"
                 styleClass="........."/>
```

It works in my case for prime faces

Comment: he want "global" not "specific" table

Answer (score 2):

Primefaces datatable has "filteredValue" option. Let's assume you set filtered values like; filteredValue="#managedBean.filteredObjects}".

filteredObjects has the same type with datatable's value which is "managedBean.objects" in your case. Before you load datatable, set filteredObjects variable to NULL. It will solve your problem.